# All keyboard arrow keys do not work

Tags: pi-4, keyboard, emulation

(I am new new to pi, so please be specific)

The version of Pi is 4

It runs Emulation Station v2. 1BRP

It’s a Raspberry Pi 3 running Retropie 4.3 I believe.

I am trying to play a game called Rags to Riches using the Commodore 64 emulation. Playing this game must have keyboard arrows. I have tested Bluetooth and wired keyboard on my retropie and the arrows do not work on any. The arrow keys also do not work outside of the game, just the letters and numbers.

Any suggestions would be

Comment: Check which keyboard standard is active (Change Keyboard Layout under Localization) usually US keyboard is what you are after but may differ depending on what keyboard that is.  if that doesnt work, try directly editing /etc/default/keyboard

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know if this question is allowed, but could you explain what to select to change the keyboard?

Comment: What will work depends on your hardware.  You can try a few that seem to be us keyboards, or skip to directly editing /etc/default/keyboard to say "us" instead of "gb" or whatever it says after "XKBLAYOUT=" as that seems to have a high success rate for the effort put in.